# How to fill an array by extracting a partial array

Tags: c, arrays

I was trying to fill an array,xlow, by extracting some elements from an array called exit_2. By making the array xlow, I wanted access specific elements of it but the code gives some weird numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int exit_1[4]={3,0,7,11},exit_2[4]={90,164,232,328},xlow[2],i;
 for(i=0;i<4;++i){
    if(exit_1[i]<7){
        xlow[2]=exit_2[i];
    }
}
 printf("%d",xlow[0]);
 return 0;
}
```

Thank you your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xlow[2]=exit_2[i];
```

As you see you are initializing `xlow[2]`. `xlow[0]` is still uninitialized and using uninitialized variables lead to undefined behavior.

```
int j=0;
 for(i=0;i<4;++i){
    if(exit_1[i]<7){
        if(j>1)
        break;
        else
        xlow[j++]=exit_2[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get weird numbers because `xlow[0]` is never written to or initialized, you only ever write to `xlow[2]`.

That means when you do `printf("%d",xlow[0]);`, the program will just print whatever random values are in the memory location of xlow[0].